# Oracle 11g can't connect to localhost after restarting

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I recently installed a fresh copy of Oracle 11g XE 64 bit on Windows 7. Right after I installed everything was working fine and I was able to connect via jdbc and SquirrelSQL. However, after I restart my PC I am not longer able to connect. This is the error message I get:

> Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection.
>   class java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null

When I get the timeout error everything looks normal when I run lsnrctl status (I replaced computer name with localhost below)

> Listening Endpoints Summary...
>
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
>
> Services Summary...
>
> Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s). Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>
> Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s). Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>
> Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s). Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>
> Service "xe" has 1 instance(s). Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

When I attempt to restart the listener and db service I receive this error message:

> ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

When I run lsnrctl status again the 8080 end point is gone and the XE service is no longer available.

I've tried a number of suggestions. Changed the listener.ora file to add the XE service under SID_LIST and then restarting the services. However, this will only temporarily fix the issue. The next time my computer reboots I run into the same problems.

Another note is that I am able to connect fine via SQL PLUS using the connect command. However if I try to run connect system@xe and then type in the password the prompt hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Q: You don't have your Oracle listener running on port 8080 (typically used by a Tomcat web server/servlet container), do you?  Q: You don't expect your app to work, if `lsnrctl` fails, do you?

Comment: @paulsm4 A: I am using the default setup for the Windows 64 bit install. I believe the listener runs on 8080, yes. Also I'm not running Tomcat or another web server on 8080. A: I'm not sure what you mean - lsnrctl is not failing - it in fact appears to be running but I still get a TimeoutException.

Comment: What is the connection URL that you are using to connect?  Also, check if you can connect to the database with the following URL 

>sqlplus username/password@<hostname>:<portid>/<service_name>

Refer to the DataSourceSample.java (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionManagementSamples/DataSourceSample.java)

Comment: @Nirmala The jdbc connection url is: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE`. When I try to connect with your url I see the prompt hang indefinitely.

Comment: After a while of waiting it gave the error message `ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact`